# Visual Studio insist on saving in OneDrive?

Tags: visual-studio

When I created a new website project, the sln file is properly located on `<username>/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/<projectname>/<projectname.sln>,` however the website itself is not located in `<username>/Visual Studio 2015/WebSites/<projectname>` as usual, instead it was stored in `OneDrive/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/WebSites`. How can I change this so websites are store in `WebSites` folder in the same location as `Projects` folder?

I have tried to change the default project, item template, and project template location in Option, but VS still saves the websites in OneDrive.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and this question came up when searching.

In Visual Studio 2015, go to `Tools -> Options`, select `Projects and Solutions`, and then change your location folders there.